# How to set conditions that have dependencies in WiX?

Tags: wix, wix3

I am making an installer, which need read a registry key and get a value, then use this value to access another registry then get the INSTALL dir.
Any condition mentioned above will stop the installation if fails.

How to set such conditions that one is dependent on the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use RegistrySearch then a Condition element in the Product element using the Property from the result of the RegistrySearch.